# Textareas not showing more then one new line in a row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that inserts blob text into a database.

When i insert it into the database using a textarea, it works fine.

For example, if i put this text into the textarea field:

```
test


ss
f



f
f




dsdfdsf


sdfsdfsdf
```

it saves it into the database as:

```
test


ss
f



f
f




dsdfdsf


sdfsdfsdf
```

So thats fine, now when i fetch the data from the database and echo it onto a div, i use nl2br(), and the divs content becomes:

```
test


ss
f



f
f




dsdfdsf


sdfsdfsdf
```

So thats still fine

HOWEVER

If i echo the output from the database into a textarea, it becomes:

```
test
ss
f
f
f
dsdfdsf
sdfsdfsdf
```

That is not using nl2br, if i do use nl2br, the textarea becomes:

```
test<br /><br /><br />ss<br />f<br /><br /><br /><br />f<br />f<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />dsdfdsf<br /><br /><br />sdfsdfsdf
```

And i want new lines, not (br /), you can see it knows how many lines there should be, but when i dont use nl2br, it will only do up to 1 new line in a row.

Ive tried googling around, and all i can find is people asking how to echo the database content to a div, but for me, it works fine to a div (with nl2br), its just to a textarea...

Ive also tried giving the textarea the css attribute: 'white-space: pre;', but that doesnt work either.

Comment: What do you do when insterting input field to db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `nl2br` if you are outputing the data into a textarea. Just output the data (with htmlspecialchars).

The textarea will see the \n (newlines) as a div will see `<br />`.

http://jsbin.com/uzinut/1

Comment: Yeah, thats my original thought, but it makes the text area, like the second last code block, without all the new lines between them. Its still got new lines, just not all of them...

Comment: Oh i am a fool, i found the problem, it was cos i was just minifying the html... And it removed all new lines. Your post helped me realize though, so i gave you tick.